# Get the first and last row values by unique id in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe for location traces similar to this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1,1,1,2,2],
    'lat': [41.144540, 41.144540, 41.163172, 41.163233, 41.163198],
    'lon': [-8.562926, -8.562926, -8.583821, -8.583838, -8.583886   ] 
})

df

    id    lat         lon
0   1   41.144540   -8.562926
1   1   41.144540   -8.562926
2   1   41.163172   -8.583821
3   2   41.163233   -8.583838
4   2   41.163198   -8.583886
```

So I want to add a new column for the length of each trip (i.e. by each id).
So for example to compute the length of trip id=1 I will use the begin and end  coordinates this way:

```
from geopy.distance import vincenty

coords_1 = (41.144540,  -8.562926)
coords_2 = (41.163172   -8.583821)

length = vincenty(coords_1, coords_2).m
length
1217881.558204788
```

And similarly to 2, and the rest. But I would like to do this with pandas dataframe.

Expected output:

```
    id    lat         lon       length
0   1   41.144540   -8.562926  1217881.5582
1   1   41.144540   -8.562926  1217881.5582
2   1   41.163172   -8.583821  1217881.5582
3   2   41.163233   -8.583838  5.5979928
4   2   41.163198   -8.583886  5.5979928
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.apply(...)`

```
def get_length(group):
  
  coords = group[['lat', 'lon']].values
  p1, p2 = coords[0], coords[-1]
    
  length = vincenty(p1, p2).m

  return length
```

---

```
grouped = df.groupby(by=['id'])
length = grouped.apply(get_length).rename('length')

df.merge(length, on=['id'])
```

---

```
    id     lat         lon       length
0   1   41.144540   -8.562926   2712.533677
1   1   41.144540   -8.562926   2712.533677
2   1   41.163172   -8.583821   2712.533677
3   2   41.163233   -8.583838   5.597993
4   2   41.163198   -8.583886   5.597993
```

Answer (score 2):

I could not get `vincenty` to work, apparently it has been superseded by `geodesic`. But this should work:

```
from geopy.distance import geodesic

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1,1,1,2,2],
    'lat': [41.144540, 41.144540, 41.163172, 41.163233, 41.163198],
    'lon': [-8.562926, -8.562926, -8.583821, -8.583838, -8.583886   ] 
})


res = (df.groupby(by='id').agg(start_lat=pd.NamedAgg(column='lat', aggfunc='first'), 
                              start_long=pd.NamedAgg(column='lon', aggfunc='first'),
                              end_lat = pd.NamedAgg(column='lat', aggfunc='last'), 
                              end_long=pd.NamedAgg(column='lon', aggfunc='last'))
        .apply(lambda f: geodesic((f['start_lat'], f['start_long']), (f['end_lat'], f['end_long'])), axis=1)
        .reset_index()
        )

df = df.merge(res, on='id').rename(columns={0: 'dist'})

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first and last values in a single command using `groupby()` and [`agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) (aka `aggregate()`):

```
df.groupby('id').agg({'lat': ['first', 'last'], 'lon': ['first', 'last']})
```

That gives you:

```
          lat                  lon          
        first       last     first      last
id                                          
1   41.144540  41.163172 -8.562926 -8.583821
2   41.163233  41.163198 -8.583838 -8.583886
```

Which is almost exactly what you need to feed to `vincenty()` to compute the distances for each `id`.